# double backslash python os.path.abspath

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.path

I get the path

```
dire=os.path.abspath(".")
```

and

```
for fileName in filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(path=direc))
```

but `dire` has `C:\\` and sends me the next error:

```
TypeError: listdir() takes no keyword arguments
```

when I print `dire` to see the content print next:

```
C:\\user\\documents....
```

what can I do to get `\` and not `\\` in `os.path.abspath(".")`?

Comment: You are confusing the *representation* with the *value*. Use `print(dire)` to see the difference. The `\\` are a Python notation for *string literals*, where you need to escape backslashes to preserve their meaning.

Comment: Is that `direc` a typo?

Comment: And why not try using a *positional* argument for `os.listdir()`? So `os.listdir(direc)`? The backslashes are never the cause of an error message about keyword arguments not working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by `print` you mean `repr`.

```py
s = 'C:\\'
s
>>> 'C:\\'
print(s)
>> C:\
```

Note that while printing there aren't neither double `\\` nor `'`

The other point is the error `TypeError: listdir() takes no keyword arguments`
so why dont try:

```py
for fileName in filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(direc))
```

instead of

```py
for fileName in filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(path=direc))
```