# Replace two backslashes with a single backslash

Tags: python-3.x, replace, filepath, backslash

I want to replace a string with two backslashes with single backslashes. However replace doesn't seem to accept '\\' as the replacement string. Here's the interpreter output:

```
>>> import tempfile
>>> temp_folder = tempfile.gettempdir()
>>> temp_folder
'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
>>> temp_folder.replace('\\\\', '\\')
'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
```

BTW, I know that Windows paths need to contain either double backslashes or a single forward slashes. I want to replace them anyway for display purposes.

Comment: mixing up data representation with data display. Try `print(temp_folder)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [double backslash python os.path.abspath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787401/double-backslash-python-os-path-abspath)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output doesn't have double backslashes. What you are looking at is the `repr()` value of the string and that displays with escaped backslashes. Assuming your `temp_folder` would have double backslashes, you should instead use:

```
print(temp_folder.replace('\\\\', '\\'))
```

and that will show you:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
```

which also drops the quotes.

But your `temp_folder` is unlikely to have double backslashes and this difference in display probably got you thinking that there are double backslashes in the return value from `tempfile.gettempdir()`. As @Jean-Francois indicated, there should not be (at least not on Windows). So you don't need to use the `.replace()`, just print:

```
print(temp_folder)
```

Comment: there's no need to replace any backslashes. The paths are OK as they are.

Comment: You are right. Windows is rather restricted in what it allows as characters in file- and directory-names.

Comment: then you should remove the `replace('\\\\', '\\')` part it makes no sense.

Comment: IMO it makes sense in the context of what the OP originally assumed (a false assumption, but anyway). I updated the answer once more, hope it is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
text = input('insert text')
list = text.split('\\')
print(list)
text2 = ''
for items in list:
    if items != '':
        text += items + '\\'
print(text2)
```