# curl from multiple URLs that have backslashes

Tags: python-3.x, curl

I writing a python script to run multiple curl commands (I only listed one as an example) that fetch some content from created URLs. However, as shown in the example, the URLs have a backslash which is interpreted, while being executed, as a double backslash.
So this is one command I want to run (notice the backslash after "fff"), which runs fine if I copy it and paste it in Linux Ubuntu terminal:

```
curl https://api.example.com/fff\|2021-06-25--15-11-33/files -H 'Authorization: JWT eykjgjgjgkjgg'
```

This is my code:

```
 import subprocess
 import shlex

 curl= "curl https://api.example.com/fff\|2021-06-25--15-11-33/files -H 'Authorization: JWT eykjgjgjgkjgg'"
    
 curlx=shlex.split(curl, posix=False)
 print(curlx[1])
 #the result of the printed URL is a valid url (with single backslash).
 print(curlx)
 #the result of the printed full command shows the invalid url (with double backslash)
 result= subprocess.run(curlx, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
 print(result)
```

but I keep getting this error because, as shown from the result,  the command runs with double backslash (after "fff") instead of one:

```
#result of first print (curlx[1]):
https://api.example.com/fff\|2021-06-25--15-11-33/files

#result of second print (curlx):
curl https://api.example.com/fff\\|2021-06-25--15-11-33/files -H 'Authorization: JWT eykjgjgjgkjgg'

#result of third print (result):  
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100   232  100   232    0     0    163      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   163
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0CompletedProcess(args=['curl', 'https://api.example.com/fff\\|2021-06-25--15-11-33/files', '-H', "'Authorization: JWT eykjgjgjgkjgg'"], returncode=0, stdout=b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>\n')
```

I tried replacing the two backslashes with a single one but that still gets interpreted as two and hence the error keeps showing. I appreciate any help because I have more than 500 curl commands that will take a long time to run manually.

FYI, I'm using Python 3.8 in Pycharm 2021.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS

Comment: "have a backslash that is interpreted in python 3 as a double backslash" -- sorry, but that's probably where the misunderstanding already starts. In general, in source code, some characters have a special meaning. In order to use them as plain characters, you escape them. How, when and why depends on the environment. In your case, there's simply not enough info to tell where you're going wrong, probably `shlex.split` and maybe more. That's also why a [mcve] is mandatory for such questions here. As a relatively new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask] again perhaps.

Comment: Thanks.
I just updated it to clarify it as much as I can without disclosing the API information.

Comment: `cmd` is undefined. Sorry, but please read [mcve] carefully! If a single URL doesn't work, there's no point iterating over a list of them, just to pick one example.

Comment: Fixed "cmd". Also got rid of the list of strings. Now I have only one string as an example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The string displayed in the exception is the `repr()` of the string, not the actual string. The `repr` value of the string is always displayed with escaped backslashes.
If you try to `print(row.iloc[0])`, you should see that it contains one backslash as expected.

See this answer for more information : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44667847/6825584

But this is not the problem in your case.
Here, the problem is that you are not splitting correctly the first argument of `subprocess.Popen`. It expects the first argument to be an array, that should contain in your case :

```py
['curl',
 'https://api.example.com/fff\|2021-06-25--15-11-33/files',
 '-H',
 "'Authorization: JWT eykjgjgjgkjgg'",
 '>>',
 'fff|2021-06-25--15-11-33.txt']
```

You can achieve this result using `shlex.split(row.iloc[0], posix=False)`. Note that `posix=False` here will keep your backslashes intact.

Again, when running this command in the interpretor, you will see that it prints two backslashes, but when using `print()`, it displays correctly one backslash as expected.

```py
In [19]: curl = "curl https://api.example.com/fff\|2021-06-25--15-11-33/files -H 'Authorization: JWT eykjgjgjgkjgg' >> fff|2021-06-25--15-11-33.txt"

In [20]: shlex.split(curl, posix=False)
Out[20]:
['curl',
 'https://api.example.com/fff\\|2021-06-25--15-11-33/files',
 '-H',
 "'Authorization: JWT eykjgjgjgkjgg'",
 '>>',
 'fff|2021-06-25--15-11-33.txt']

In [21]: shlex.split(curl, posix=False)[1]
Out[21]: 'https://api.example.com/fff\\|2021-06-25--15-11-33/files'

In [22]: print(shlex.split(curl, posix=False)[1])
https://api.example.com/fff\|2021-06-25--15-11-33/files
```

Comment: Thank you but the curl commands still get interpreted as double backslash when they run!

Comment: What makes you think this ? Are you sure that is not again Python displaying the `repr` ?
Maybe you could try to use `curl -v` to print the URL directly from inside the curl command, or use an `echo` command instead of the curl

Comment: Actually, after running -v the url in GET is valid. Does this mean that this has nothing to do with the backslash? maybe the server only responds to commands that are coming from the terminal? However, comparing the -v output from the terminal and the script I could not find any difference that indicates the server is treating them differently. Maybe the server is hiding some information.

Comment: It should have no difference since Python is using the same `curl`. Did you try to run manually in the terminal the output of `print(' '.join(shlex.split(curl, posix=False)))` ? (again, note the `print`). The output of this command is exactly what is ran by the subprocess and it should _not_ work either if it doesn't work in Python.

Comment: just tried it andit shows the correct url

Comment: I meant to run the command manually from the terminal, just to be sure that the command is valid and the URL is indeed a valid URL from curl's view. Could you make sure that, if running the command that is outputted by the command I've linked you, it correctly returns an HTTP 200 ?